# AndEngine Fragments

Tags: android, andengine

I just started working with AndEngine and I was wondering if anyone could help me create two fragments to split the screen. I tried using the split screen functionality in AndEngine, but that just copies the screen. I would like to create two independently running halves. The left screen is to be a scrollable menu type screen with buttons which will change what a touch will do on the right screen.

So what I have been trying to do is set up two fragments. One to run a normal view and the other to run the AndEngine. So far I have not gotten it to work.

Does anyone have any idea on how to code this or have a better suggestion to achieve the same result?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I not sure, maybe this issue is already implemented in AndEngine, but I invented workaround:

```
Scene childScene = new Scene();
childScene.attachChild(your menu element sprite with onAreaTouched);
... here will be attached all other menu elements.
childScene.setBackgroundEnabled(false); // to make transparent background
mainScene.setChildScene(childScene, false, false, false);
```

after that, make physics box (look in PhysicsExample.java), but change 
final Rectangle ground, roof, left X coords to CAMERA_WIDTH / 2 (to make half of screen)

Comment: I followed this tutorial for my main activity: https://sites.google.com/site/matimdevelopment/splash-screen---easy-way

How would I implement the childScene without changing the format of my splashscreen? Would you be interested in taking a look at my code so far to be able to give me a more specific answer? Thank you.

I tried running the AndEngine Example code (containing PhysicsExample.java), but it crashes on me because there are still some import statements that don't work for me.

Comment: "without changing the format of my splashscreen" - I don't understand about what format you talking about. And why you need splash screen to create menu scene?

Comment: The way the code is now I implemented a main camera, had a splash screen show up upon startup, then dismiss it and show main screen. On this main screen I would like the split to occur and the menu section to appear. Did that explain it better?

Comment: Yes thanks, http://www.filedropper.com/splashscreentemplate - here is project from first comment. I edited it. Take a look. Don't forget to change paths of andengine and box2d (in Project Properties -> Android -> Library

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help me. So far I have included all the necessary .jar files, but it crashes upon start up. I will take a look at which changes you made tonight and I'll get back to you. :)

Comment: Can you provide your stacktrace?

Comment: 11-18 10:26:32.080: I/dalvikvm(23352): Could not find method org.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef, referenced from method socs.acad.ACadEngineActivity.<clinit>
11-18 10:26:32.080: W/dalvikvm(23352): VFY: unable to resolve static method 6399: Lorg/andengine/extension/physics/box2d/PhysicsFactory;.createFixtureDef (FFF)Lcom/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/FixtureDef;

... 
Would it be possible to email you my code?

Comment: This is what happens if I try to run yours:

11-18 10:57:22.624: W/dalvikvm(26271): Unable to resolve superclass of Lmatim/development/SplashTemplate; (73)
11-18 10:57:22.624: W/dalvikvm(26271): Link of class 'Lmatim/development/SplashTemplate;' failed
11-18 10:57:22.624: D/AndroidRuntime(26271): Shutting down VM
11-18 10:57:22.634: E/AndroidRuntime(26271): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-18 10:57:22.634: E/AndroidRuntime(26271): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{matim.development/matim.development.SplashTemplate}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ...

Answer (score 2):

IF you want to be able set buttons on screen you'd better use HUD(head-up display). You'l just describe the functionality of your buttons and add them into HUD.
the example of HUD realization:

```
HUD hud = new HUD();
getEngine.getCamera().setHUD(hud);
hud.attachChild(your_button);
```

Comment: Thank you. This will come in use for a edit/delete button that I want to implement, but I'm not sure how I can use this for the menu. I would like to implement tabs which will change the icons for the "buttons". This section is to be scrollable.

Comment: Tijgerlili, use the HUD probably would be better than child scene, because it written special for this purposes. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HUD_(video_gaming) If you will successfully run my code, you can later replace child scene with HUD.

Comment: Hud is also a child scene, but with some features. You may use it as scene, and I think it will be the issue

Comment: It's a method of the BaseGameActivity.